# USB based Mechanical keyboard not getting detected in my two Computers but getting detected at Technician's computer

Tags: keyboard

My TVS-E Bharat Gold keyboard is not getting detected in my computer while its getting detected in the keyboard Technician's computer. I have tried on my two different PC's, OS = Windows7 & xubuntu. The Laptop is Lenovo z570 (2013 model) and desktop is Dual Core Lenovo (2007 Model).
I have checked in the BIOS too, it won't work on my computers but again work on the computer of the Technician.

I even tried using it on mobile via OTG cable. When I used it on Mobile post using on my computers then it **won't work** on mobile too. BUT when I tried it on mobile post plugging into Technician's computer it **worked** on mobile.

Such a strange issue, I couldn't conclude anything
Is there any possibility of voltage variation at USB port on my PC and Technician's computer?

Comment: It's broken, get it replaced or buy a new one.

Comment: @gronostaj Plz check the question again, I have made some edits.